# Обратный отсчёт времени?

Tags: время, php

Как сделать обратный отсчёт времени на PHP?

1. Время берёться из БД, пусть она будет $date_bd
2. Текущее время $date = time()
3. Разность: $date2 = $date-$date_bd
4. Условие: Если $date_2>=900, То:..

Как сделать, чтобы шёл отсчёт времени, например: "Подождите, осталось 14.мин" 13.мин, и т.п?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью ajax, по таймеру, допустим раз в минуту, или раз в секунду отправлять запрос на сервер и узнавать сколько осталось.

Либо передать значение `$date` и `$date2` в js, каждую секунду в js уменьшать `$date` и при выполнении условия отправлять запрос на сервер(если он нужен) для выполнения какого-либо действия.

2й вариант предпочтительнее, чтоб не не дергать каждый раз базу данных и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, решил проблему иначе, просто к $date2 прибавил 900